# Otherwise-statement in XSLT-choose is not applied/working

Tags: xslt, conditional-statements

I have an XML-document with a *type*-node whose value is either "1" or "2":

```
<MyDoc>
  <foo>
    <bar>
      <type>2</type>
    </bar>
  </foo>
</MyDoc>
```

I want to set a variable *typeBool* depending on the value of the type-node, if it is "1" it should be set to *false*, if it's "2" to *true*.

With the [XSLT-choose-Element](https://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/xsltc/xsl_choose_design.html) it should be possible to test for the current value and set *typeBool* according to the outcome.

I'm trying to do this with the following construct in XSLT 2.0, but I'm puzzled that the *"otherwise"*-path is not applied and I get an error that *typeBool* is not created:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

  <xsl:variable name="type" select="/MyDoc/foo/bar/type/text()"/>
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$type = '2'">
      <xsl:variable name="typeBool">true</xsl:variable>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:variable name="typeBool">false</xsl:variable>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>

  <h1><b><xsl:value-of select="$typeBool"/></b></h1>
</xsl:transform>
```

This is the transformation error I get:

```
error during xslt transformation:

Source location: line 0, col 0 Description:
No variable with name typeBool exists
```

Comment: Please show a [complete, minimal](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) XSLT stylesheet and an input XML document. Otherwise, nobody can reproduce your issue. State what your _goal_ is and show the expected output. This is important even if you self-answer your question because your attempted solution might not be ideal.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I've adapted my question a bit

Comment: Please also specify XSLT 1.0 or 2.0. (I imagine this is 1.0 because in 2.0 the problem would be trivial, but a lot of trivial problems get posted here...)

Comment: @MichaelKay It's 2.0 - thanks, I've added this information to the header. While it might be trivial for an author of a XSLT-book, everyone has to start somewhere... ;-)

Comment: Well in 2.0, you don't need xsl:choose, you can use an XPath if..then..else. For example `<xsl:variable name="testbool" select="if($type=2) then 'T' else 'F'"/>`.

Comment: @MichaelKay Ah, neat. Thanks, I've added this in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### With choose-element

The choose-clause has to be defined *inside* of the variable-declaration:

```
<xsl:variable name="type">
   <xsl:value-of select="/MyDoc/foo/bar/type/text()"/>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="typeBool">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$type = '2'">true</xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>false</xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
```

The conditional also looks cleaner this way.

### With XSLT 2.0

@MichaelKay pointed out that in XSLT 2.0 a xpath-conditional can be used, which is even simpler:

```
<xsl:variable name="type">
   <xsl:value-of select="/MyDoc/foo/bar/type/text()"/>
</xsl:variable>
<h1>
  <b>
    <xsl:value-of select="select="if($type=2) then 'true' else 'false'"/>
  </b>
</h1>
```

Comment: To clarify: variables are scoped to their parent element. In your example, you have two variables (both named `typeBool`); the former is scoped to its parent `xsl:when`, and the latter to its parent `xsl:otherwise`. You are trying to access these variables from higher up in the tree, where they are undefined.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

As you currently present your problem, an `xsl:choose` is not needed and it unnecessarily complicates your XSLT code. Your actual problem might be more intricate though.

You can write a template that matches the element you are interested in (for instance, `type` elements) and then simply select the value of a comparison that will evaluate to either true or false.

**XSLT Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="type">
      <h1>
          <b>
              <xsl:value-of select=". = '2'"/>
          </b>
      </h1>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()"/>

</xsl:transform>
```

**HTML Output**

```
<h1><b>true</b></h1>
```

Try it online [here](http://xsltransform.net/bFWR5EG).